# Xcode 9 : Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, cocoapods, facebook-login, xcode9-beta, swift4

After updating to Xcode 9, I tried to build one of my projects.

I use the **FacebookLogin** pod.
I have a compiler error in FacebookLogin/LoginButton.swift

```
@testable import FacebookCore
❌ Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0
```

In my target's build settings, the Swift language version is set to **Swift 3.2**.

[image: Screenshot added]

I guess I need to wait for Facebook to update their pod ? Or any other suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can try to folk that.

Comment: [Try cleaning the project from Product -> Clean in Xcode 8 and build again.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44536185/5372683)

Answer (score 73):

**Update:**

Solution also tested and working in Swift 5 and Xcode 11.

**Original:**

I would like to add that if you are using **Carthage** to compile a module in Swift 3.2 you should go to a terminal and run:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

To use the Xcode 9 command line tools, then you can run:

```
carthage update NameOfTheLibrary --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

This will compile the library with your current command line tools, it can be a bit slow but now the project should build.

*Note*

To revert and use your stable Xcode command line tools simply run:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: I had the same error using Algolia framework, and build it with carthage and Xcode 9 command tool worked fine ! Thanks

Comment: Worked for me using SwiftyJson. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me using Alamofire

Comment: Hi @xaviPedrals, I need your help... Im trying to run that project "https://github.com/swiftingio/SingTest"  but getting that error "Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler: /Users/aliapple/Desktop/SingTestByAhtazaz/Pods/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit.framework/Modules/AudioKit.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule". Can you help me in this?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Ahtazaz that project is from 2 years ago so probably it was made and compiled in Swift 3, first the project should be updated to Swift 4 or 5, then try running the carthage command `carthage update NameOfTheLibrary --platform iOS --no-use-binaries` to update the libraries and you should be okay

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @xaviPedrals. I have updated this project in swift 4.2. All things are Perfect but getting this ""Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler: /Users/aliapple/Desktop/SingTestByAhtazaz/Pods/AudioKit/iOS/AudioKit.framework/Modules/AudioKit.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftmodule"" ERROR on POD AudioKit.

Comment: @xaviPedrals I have got your instructions but dont know how to use carthage.. I just familiar with POds not carthage... Can you help me with that. I will be very Thankful to you Sir.

Comment: @vaviPedrals after running command on Terminal, got "-bash: carthage: command not found"

Comment: @xavi.pedrals i have update th eproject on latest Swift 4.2 but now only issue is coming on AudioKit... So how do i update AUDIOKIT Pod on latest version?

Comment: @xavi.pedrals Actually the problem is that, currently there are 3 PODS Installed in this project.
pod 'TuningFork' 
pod 'UICircularProgressRing' 
pod 'ResearchKit' 

TuningFork depends on AudioKit & Chronos-Swift. So when i installed TuningFork, it automatically installs AudioKit & Chronos-Swift (but with old Language version). 

So, how do i update only AUDIOKIT & CHRONOS-SWIFT POD using TuningFork?

Answer (score 26):

Xcode 9 comes with a Swift 4 compiler that understands both Swift 3.2 and swift 4, it even lets you mix and match between the 2 versions. Unfortunately, other versions aren't supported.

**Even if you set your language to Swift 3.2, it uses the Swift 4 compiler.**

If you're using cocoapods, you can add this to the end of your pod file to force the pods to use Swift 3.2 or 4.0:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
        end
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could put the files from the pod directly into your project temporarily, until FacebookLogin is updated to Swift 3.2 or 4.

*Note: Edited based on Matt's feedback*

Comment: FYI - This is somewhat overly aggressive by forcing all pods to Swift 4.0. If a pod is Swift 3 compliant, you can safely bump to Swift 3.2. Bumping to 4.0 will more than likely cause compiler issues for many pods.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe you can clean the target before you build it.
It works fine for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me, still looking for another solution.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same issue on Xcode 9 Beta 3, which pointing to 'Alamofire' and tried a few different solutions, the easiest one i found is

```
1. CMD+SHIFT+K to clean the build
2. Restart Xcode 9 <-- make sure you do this step, that's critical. `
```

Comment: It's 2017 and we still need to restart Xcode to solve bugs. Thank you, Apple. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Doing a "clean build folder" and restarting Xcode 9 cleaned up the error for me. Also the error didn't stop the app from running on my device or the simulator.

Comment: "clean build folder": To access the option open the Product menu and use the Option key to show the Clean Build Folder option.

Answer (score 8):

goto xcode DerivedData directory then remove all file inside it  and recompile your project . it work for me .

and default DerivedData directory is :~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

Answer (score 8):

If using **Carthage** , Open **terminal** and;

```
carthage update --platform iOS --no-use-binaries
```

If using **Pod** , Open **terminal** and;

```
pod update
```

(Also if don't work in pod, you can change SWIFT_VERSION in podfile Ex:

```
config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.2'
```

)

**After;**

Open Xcode and use;

```
Command+Option+Shift+K
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/311792

Comment: @paper1111 I explain everything in my answer and works

Comment: I'm using carthage and this is the solution that worked for me. carthage update "My Framework" did not cut it. I had to update the entire carthage catalogue. Took forever but did the trick.

Comment: This solution also worked for me. To be double sure make sure you close and relaunch xcode after cleaning the build folder with Command+Option+Shift+K.

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper Where does the `config.build_settings` portion go?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me.

1.Clean your project in Xcode 8

2.Build or run your project in Xcode 9

Answer (score 3):

I cleaned the project in Xcode 9, and then run the app, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Xcode 9 GM and this solved my problem:
Remove it from the project and drag it again into "Embedded Binaries".

Comment: I had the issue with Alamofire 4.5.1 and tried everything else on this page via `pod update` but without result. In the end I added the framework directly to my project and added it to my Embedded Binaries which worked

Answer (score 2):

Clean Build Folder

```
Cmd + option + shift + K
```

Answer (score 1):

I have

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

in my project and `import FBSDKLoginKit`, after cleaning the target i didn't have any issue

Since the pod you are using is in swift and is a beta pod, it is likely that you would have some issues with the swift 4 compiler, you should use the objective-c version of the pod for the time being

Answer (score 0):

If you use from Pod:

1. In `Podfile` comment FacebookLogin pod
2. > pod install
3. In `Podfile` uncomment FacebookLogin pod
4. > pod install
5. Run again your project

Answer (score 0):

For my case - the actual pod referenced a static zip with prebuilt binaries targeting swift 3.1. 
So only solution is to rebuild the framework with source from xcode 9.

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/980

Comment: I have a similar issue with AudioKit being referenced inside pods. However, your solution refers to a build_frameworks.sh found in the 'Framework' Please add more details. I cannot find such a file.

Comment: try to point the podfile to a newer release. a version that's been built with latest xcode 9 - / no build script changes needed. https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I had to update the AudioKit version in cocoapods to the latest one, which had the build_frameworks.sh. The build_frameworks.sh was needed to 'validate' AudioKit, to stop Apple rejecting the app.