# Module compiled with swift 4.0 cannot be imported in swift 3.0.2

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, xcode8

I just used Xcode 9 beta version and did not even compile my app. Now I am not able to run it in Xcode 8. The framework import is giving error. I have to give the archive. Help please. In the snapshot attached , I am importing an external framework MMCardView written in swift. Now that is throwing error in Xcode 8. What should i do?[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try cleaning the project from Product -> Clean in Xcode 8 and build again.

Comment: The problem still persists. I will try restarting my mac now.

Comment: You can try cleaning the complete build folder. Hold the option key and click on Product -> Clean build folder

Comment: Not Working For Me