# Are playgrounds in Xcode 9 compiled with Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, rx-swift, xcode9-beta

I have a project I am trying out which is fine in Xcode 8. However, in Xcode 9 the RxSwift framework won't import into the playground. I get the following error

> Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0: 
>   /Volumes/HGST3tb/CloudStation/Development/Frameworks/GuideView/GuideView/Carthage/Build/tvOS/RxSwift.framework/Modules/RxSwift.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

All frameworks apart from RxSwift are swift 3.2 but the error seems to imply that the playgrounds are compiled with 4.0. I can't see any settings to be able to change this.

Comment: I appreciate the module is 3.1 vice 3.2 but I am curious about the 4.0 error in the playground.

Answer (score 0):

From how I interpret Apple's documentation, it should be possible.  I believe that Xcode 9 compiles in Swift 4.0 regardless though and just supports the backwards compatibility.

> One compiler for Swift 4 and Swift 3, Swift 4 and Swift 3 targets can
>   be compiled together in the same project.

Referencing [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399109/xcode-9-module-compiled-with-swift-3-1-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0?rq=1) you should try Shift+Command+K to clean your project.  Unfortunately, I've been having cross-compatibility issues on things that should work too, though.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  It would appear I just need to compile the rxswift project again.